# I need to identify local users vs. sssd users in /etc/bashrc

Tags: linux, security, ldap, centos7

I have a CentOS system. There are local users (root, etc.) and Active Directory users via sssd/realm. Is there a way in /etc/bashrc to test for local users?

I'm using a structure like this:

```
GROUPS=`id -Gr $USER`
for i in "${GROUPS[@]}"; do
 #admin check
 if [ $i == 199299399 ]; then
```

to identify specific groups for the Active Directory users. It isn't practical for me to enumerate all the local groups.

Answer (score 0):

Found this, which works for my situation:

```
elif [[ -z `grep $USER /etc/passwd 1> /dev/null` ]]; then
```